# TextSuggest autocomplete error on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autocomplete

I'm having an issue with [TextSuggest](https://gitlab.com/bharadwaj-raju/TextSuggest) - an automcomplete tool for Linux. It only works once, after that the shortcut doesn't open the autocomplete popup anymore. (nothing happens at all)

- My Shortcut: SHIFT+CTRL+P
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
- I added textsuggest-server in the background to run on startup

Error message after I *select* a word from the TextSuggest menu and press *enter*:

```
    go@tom:~/Desktop/TextSuggest-Pkg$ textsuggest-server
Started server at org.textsuggest.server, PID: 7678…
time get_all_words([English, English]) = 0.001719
Processing 'previous'
    Using processor 'command' from '/usr/share/textsuggest/processors/command'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 0)
/usr/bin/textsuggest-server: line 3:  7678 Aborted                 (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/share/textsuggest/libs /usr/share/textsuggest/textsuggest-server "$@"

error 2:
Started server at org.textsuggest.server, PID: 7811…
time get_all_words([English, English]) = 0.00155287
time get_all_words([English, English]) = 0.00150532
Processing 'previous'
    Using processor 'command' from '/usr/share/textsuggest/processors/command'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 0)
/usr/bin/textsuggest-server: line 3:  7811 Aborted                 (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/share/textsuggest/libs /usr/share/textsuggest/textsuggest-server "$@"
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: The program is trying to copy a part of a string starting at position 18446744073709551615 but the size of the string is 0 and crashes. You can see it's starting again with a different PID. It's best to create an issue / bug on the git repo.